# Implementing ListView - Windows Phone 8.1 RT

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, windows-phone-8.1

I have a question. In my WP8.1 RT project, I have been asked to implement a `ListView` to select a list of countries. Can I have them probably in a **text file** and have that data bound against the ListView? Or what would be the easiest way to do this? I would like to prefer the former, but if there is an easier (latter) way to do it, i'd be happy to.

BTW, I've tried to have a .cs file with a list of countries (hard coded to the list) and bound it to he ListView. As a desperate measure, I have hard coded the list of countries to the ListView directly (which i dont prefer, because it is too easy and unethical). I need to use the ListView because I will need to implement SemanticZoom.

Answer (score 2):

The ideal data source is an XML file, a well-formed XML is easier to parse than a plain text file.

Parse an XML using `Linq to XML` is as simple as these two lines of code. I find [an example](http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/wp7-working-with-xml-reading-filtering-and-databinding) for your reference.

```
XDocument loadedData = XDocument.Load("Countries.xml");

var countries = from query in loadedData.Descendants("Country").
           select new Country()...
```

Then bind the list to the ListView

```
listView1.ItemsSource = countries;
```

And you also need to define an `ItemTemplate` for the `ListView`. [This](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2014/07/01/gridview-and-listview-controls.aspx) is an example for this part.

Comment: thnx for that. Will try that and let you know.